Windows 11 won't wake up Buffalo NAS LinkStations
This question is regarding anything specific to Windows 11.
On my Lenovo Ideapad with AMD Ryzen 5 7520U with Radeon Graphics, I am running Windows 11 Home. I have NasNavigator v3.11.0 installed, NAS PM service is installed and running.  NIC has Wake On Magic Packet enabled (Realtex 8822CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E).
I also have two Buffalo NAS, A LS-WXL/R1 and a LS-WVL/R1.
Here's the challenge: This computer won't wake up the two Buffalo NAS LinkStations. Both are set on Auto and both wake up when either of the other two Windows 10 computers are switched on. It is just this particular computer they will not wake up for. Once they are awake, I can see them in NAS Navigator and can connect to them, create shares, etc. I just can't wake them from this computer.
I have tried running WakeMeOnLan.  Whilst the applet can see both the LinkStations while they are asleep, sending a magic packet from WakeMeOnLan doesn't wake them up.
Any thoughts?
EDIT:  I am also running Windows Defender Firewall and NordVPN with firewall - BOTH have got the NAS PM service and NAS Navigator configured as allowed programs.  I have tried to start NAS with both of those shut down.  No difference
EDIT 2:  I am by request posting the contents of the .bat file here.  The NAS' are woken (on the other two computers) using NasNavi 3.11, but that doesn't seem to work on the Lenovo ... so the .bat file is purely to connect the drives once NAS are awake.  This is so I can take my computer to another location and not have it try and connect drives that aren't on the network.

@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

TIMEOUT 120

:: Set persistence to "NO" and delete existing shares

net use /P:N > nul
net use * /DEL /YES > nul

:: Enter username and password for the drives

net use \\CEDAR /Persistent:no /user:xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx > nul
net use \\CYPRESS /Persistent:no /user:xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx > nul

:: Set the two state switches for the NAS'

set CedarState=down
set CypressState=down

:: Test if CYPRESS is available on network and allow 30 seconds for a response
:: if no response, allow a further 120 seconds for drive to become available
:: if drive is unavailable, go to test next NAS

set "i=1"
:Nasloop1
if %i%==3 goto :NextNas
echo Cypress Attempt %i%
for /f "tokens=5,6,7" %%a in ('ping 192.168.1.3 -n 1 -w 10000') do (
    if "x%%b"=="xunreachable." goto :NextNas
    if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%c"=="x0," (
        if %i% lss 2 (
           TIMEOUT 120
        )
        set /a "i+=1"
        goto :Nasloop1
        )
    if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%c"=="x1," (
        set CypressState=up
    echo Cypress Up
        goto :NextNas
        )
)

:: Test if CEDAR is available on network and allow 30 seconds for a response
:: if no response, allow a further 120 seconds for drive to become available
:: if drive is unavailable, go to check state switch of both NAS

:NextNas
set /a "i=1"

:Nasloop2
if %i%==3 goto :CHECKBOTH
echo Cedar Attempt %i%
for /f "tokens=5,6,7" %%a in ('ping 192.168.1.4 -n 1 -w 10000') do (
    if "x%%b"=="xunreachable." goto CHECKBOTH    
    if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%c"=="x0," (
        if %i% lss 2 (
           TIMEOUT 120
        )
        set /a "i+=1"
        goto :Nasloop2
        )
    if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%c"=="x1," (
        set CedarState=up
    echo Cedar Up
        goto :CONNECT
        )
)

:: Check state switches that were set.  if both "down" exit batch file

:CHECKBOTH

if %CedarState%==down (
   if %CypressState%==down (
      echo Cedar not available
      echo Cypress not available
      TIMEOUT 5
      Exit
   )
)

:: At least one NAS is up - check the state switch and connect the drive(s)

:CONNECT

if %CypressState%==down goto :CEDAR

echo Mapping M:\
net use M: "\\CYPRESS\Media" > nul

:CEDAR

if %CedarState%==down exit

echo Mapping Q:\
net use Q: "\\CEDAR\Sandstone\Downloads" > nul
echo Mapping S:\
net use S: "\\CEDAR\Sandstone" > nul
echo Mapping T:\
net use T: "\\CEDAR\Terracotta" > nul
echo Mapping U:\
net use U: "\\CEDAR\Basalt" > nul
echo Mapping V:\
net use V: "\\CEDAR\Sandstone\Audio & Video" > nul
::echo Mapping X:\
::net use X: "\\CEDAR\Dolomite\Business" > nul
echo Mapping Z:\
net use Z: "\\CEDAR\Dolomite\Business\Spanish Business" > nul
TIMEOUT 5
Exit


Does the Win11 PC have have a persistent share configured already? Windows will do a couple things on start to try and remount those shares like dns/nbns/arp discovery, depending on how they were configured. Those queries can wake some devices on their own or can trigger your router to send a WoL packet. Are the NAS devices plugged into the router? Some routers will separate wired and wireless devices to where broadcast traffic (like WoL) can't cross over. Try plugging in the win11 PC and see if it can wake the NAS devices

Unfortunately my Lenovo Ideapad doen't have an Ethernet port, so I can't plug into the router directly.  Noth NAS are connected to the router via Cat 5.
Shares are not permanent - they are configured once computer detects NAS are alive (use ping in a batch job to test if awake, then configure shares) - this is so when I shift locations to my shop, it doesnt try to connect the shares
Bothe other computers (which are much MUCH older - a HP DV7-2022tx and a HP Sleekbook Red) running Windows 10 connect to the NAS in exactly the same way, using same .bat file over wireless ...

Is that bat file how you're waking the nas from the other devices? Can you edit your question to include the contents of it? Does the WoL tool work from the Win10 devices? Just to rule out it using the wrong addresses or the nas devices not listening for it

Thanks - will edit query now.  It doesn't use the .bat file to wake them up, only to connect the drives once NasNavi has woken the drives up.  I haven't tested the WakeMeOnLan tool on the other two computers because they wake the NAS´already using NasNavi
